# SimpleXML check SimpleXML object exists

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using an if statement to check whether an XML object exists, but it does not work well as  I get `trying to get property of non-object error`

below is the code

```
foreach($resp->GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult as $product){
   $isbn = "";
   $price = "";
   $condition = "";

   if($product->Product->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN){
      $isbn = (string) $product->Product->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN;
   }

   if($product->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing->Price->LandedPrice->Amount){
      $price = (float) $product->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing->Price->LandedPrice->Amount;
   }

   if($product->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing->Qualifiers->ItemSubcondition){
      $condition = (string) $product->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing->Qualifiers->ItemSubcondition;
   }
}
```

I have tried using

```
if(!property_exists($product, 'Amount')){
   $price = (float) $product->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing->Price->LandedPrice->Amount;
}
```

but that does not work, what should I be using

**xml returned result (if price exists)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult ASIN="000726965X" status="Success">
  <AllOfferListingsConsidered>true</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
  <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
    <Identifiers>
      <MarketplaceASIN>
        <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
        <ASIN>000726965X</ASIN>
      </MarketplaceASIN>
    </Identifiers>
    <LowestOfferListings>
      <LowestOfferListing>
        <Qualifiers>
          <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubcondition>Mint</ItemSubcondition>
          <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
          <ShippingTime>
            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
          </ShippingTime>
          <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
        </Qualifiers>
        <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
        <SellerFeedbackCount>500720</SellerFeedbackCount>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>12.65</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>12.65</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>0.00</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
        <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
      </LowestOfferListing>
      <LowestOfferListing>
        <Qualifiers>
          <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubcondition>Acceptable</ItemSubcondition>
          <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
          <ShippingTime>
            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
          </ShippingTime>
          <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
        </Qualifiers>
        <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
        <SellerFeedbackCount>73208</SellerFeedbackCount>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>15.41</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>12.61</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>2.80</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
        <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
      </LowestOfferListing>
      <LowestOfferListing>
        <Qualifiers>
          <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubcondition>Mint</ItemSubcondition>
          <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
          <ShippingTime>
            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
          </ShippingTime>
          <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>98-100%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
        </Qualifiers>
        <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
        <SellerFeedbackCount>2125</SellerFeedbackCount>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>22.80</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>20.00</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>2.80</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
        <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
      </LowestOfferListing>
      <LowestOfferListing>
        <Qualifiers>
          <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubcondition>Mint</ItemSubcondition>
          <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
          <ShippingTime>
            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
          </ShippingTime>
          <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>90-94%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
        </Qualifiers>
        <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
        <SellerFeedbackCount>68301</SellerFeedbackCount>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>23.14</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>20.34</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>2.80</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
        <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
      </LowestOfferListing>
      <LowestOfferListing>
        <Qualifiers>
          <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubcondition>Mint</ItemSubcondition>
          <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ShipsDomestically>False</ShipsDomestically>
          <ShippingTime>
            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
          </ShippingTime>
          <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>90-94%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
        </Qualifiers>
        <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>2</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
        <SellerFeedbackCount>4114</SellerFeedbackCount>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>25.39</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>22.59</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>2.80</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
        <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
      </LowestOfferListing>
      <LowestOfferListing>
        <Qualifiers>
          <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubcondition>Mint</ItemSubcondition>
          <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
          <ShippingTime>
            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
          </ShippingTime>
          <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
        </Qualifiers>
        <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
        <SellerFeedbackCount>34661</SellerFeedbackCount>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>29.20</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>26.40</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>2.80</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
        <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
      </LowestOfferListing>
      <LowestOfferListing>
        <Qualifiers>
          <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubcondition>VeryGood</ItemSubcondition>
          <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ShipsDomestically>False</ShipsDomestically>
          <ShippingTime>
            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
          </ShippingTime>
          <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
        </Qualifiers>
        <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
        <SellerFeedbackCount>49504</SellerFeedbackCount>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>33.16</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>30.36</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>2.80</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
        <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
      </LowestOfferListing>
    </LowestOfferListings>
  </Product>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>09a1deae-94ec-4661-95ae-49567ab00eb8</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse>
```

**xml returned result (if price does not exist)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult ASIN="0957143826" status="Success">
  <AllOfferListingsConsidered>true</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
  <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
    <Identifiers>
      <MarketplaceASIN>
        <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
        <ASIN>0957143826</ASIN>
      </MarketplaceASIN>
    </Identifiers>
    <LowestOfferListings/>
  </Product>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>13918cb9-69e5-4445-ad24-70f6fda06f19</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse>
```

Comment: I too have the same/similar issue and was told that I need to check if child node exists.  I have not had the time to delve into this further however.  Might get you started in the right direction however.  Good Luck!

Comment: At what point in that enormous call chain does the error get raised? The problem with method/property call chains is that they are only safe to use if you *know* that everything in the chain exists and will succeed. If not, you are in danger of errors like this. What *really* sucks is that there is no clean way to force PHP to throw a catchable exception instead, but that is a little off topic. Can we see the XML source?

Comment: @DaveRandom sure just give me a minute

Comment: @DaveRandom Problem with the XML is that most of the data is there, then sometimes it is not.  It is retrieved from Amazon ( at least in my case) and there seems to be an issue with consistency right now, therefore the error can come at any given point.

Comment: @mk_89 OK the problem is that `LowestOfferListing` is an array (because there is more than one of them) and you would need to specify which one you want to use. With the above XML this would be as simple as `$product->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing[0]->Price->LandedPrice->Amount` (for the first result) but the problem *that* is that it won't be an array if there is only one of them. I think you would be best using XPath to fetch an array of possibilities which you can loop, and you can check for a zero-length result if there are no matches to handle the error gracefully.

Comment: @DaveRandom OK i'll look into it

Comment: @mk_89 Have you come up with a solution for this yet?

Comment: @jim temporarly im just using `if(isset())`

Comment: @mk_89 I tried that also, just be aware that if there is no child node, it will throw a fatal error.  Seems we are working on the same project for Amazon MWS.

Comment: @Jim that does not seem to be the case for me, actually it works really well e.g. 


`if(isset($product->Product->SalesRankings->SalesRank->Rank))
    $rank = (int) $product->Product->SalesRankings->SalesRank->Rank;
else    $rank = 999999;`

Comment: @jim what are you trying to build with Amazon MWS?, i've managed to create different functions such as creatInventoryListing setInventoryPrice etc..

Comment: @mk_89 I am using the products api to retrieve prices, rankings etc to price books. With isset() I was trying to see if their was an amount, since if there was not it would through an error.

Comment: @DaveRandom Your thoughts on arrays are incorrect: one of the pieces of magic that SimpleXML does is that if you don't mention which of a set of identically-named children you want, it gives you the first one. That is `$xmldoc->Foo` and `$xmldoc->Foo[0]` are the same thing, whether or not there is another `<Foo>` next to the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are testing too far into the chain of `->` operators:

```
if ( $product->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing->Price->LandedPrice->Amount )
```

In order to even test this, PHP must evaluate each of the `->` operators in turn

1. `$product->Product` [OK]
2. `$product->Product->LowestOfferListings` [OK]
3. `$product->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing` [An empty set if there are no prices]
4. `$product->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing->Price` [Undefined]
5. After this, you're already too late.

Additionally, the SimpleXML object won't evaluate to `false` even if it's an empty list, so you do need to use `isset`. In order to spot the no-price situation, you therefore need this:

```
if ( isset($product->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing) )
```

[Note: I haven't actually tested the above, so I may have gone wrong in some specific, but I'm pretty sure this is your basic problem.]

Comment: Thanks, I already decided to use `if(isset())` if you look at my comments above.